# How to set the value of text inputs in a table in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these text inputs in a table :

```
<td><input type='text' name='arrondi_devis_ht' class='calcul_total' size='8'></td>
<td><input type='text' name='arrondi_devis_ttc' class='calcul_total' size='8'></td>
<td><input type="text" name='marge_pourcent' class='calcul_total' size='5' value='20,0'></td>
```

I successfully get their value by performing this :

```
var prix_unitaire_ht=parseFloat($(this).parents("tr").find('input[name="arrondi_devis_ht"]').val().replace(',','.'));
var prix_unitaire_ttc=parseFloat($(this).parents("tr").find('input[name="arrondi_devis_ttc"]').val().replace(',','.'));
var marge_pourcent=parseFloat($(this).parents("tr").find('input[name="marge_pourcent"]').val().replace(',','.'));
```

So i figured i could use a similar mechanism to set their values and tried this :

```
$(this).parents("tr").find('input[name="arrondi_devis_ht"]').value=new_prix_ht;
$(this).parents("tr").find('input[name="arrondi_devis_ttc"]').value=new_prix_ttc;
$(this).parents("tr").find('input[name="marge_pourcent"]').value=new_marge;
```

Yet it does not work and their value remain unchanged. I've tried with .val instead of value, also to assign them an id and to do `find("#id").value` instead of the above without any result.

Could anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: `$(this).parents("tr").find('input[name="arrondi_devis_ht"]').val(new_prix_ht);` etc...

Comment: Did you think to google something like ["how to set input value with jquery"](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=how+to+set+input+value+with+jquery)?

Comment: @nnnnnn : I tried googling, searched on this site and the jquery doc, but maybe my terms of research were too specific, and it didn't return any pertinent anwser. I apologize and will try better next time before asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use that [`val()`](http://api.jquery/com/val) method to set the value of an input. This is what you are looking for:

```
$(this).parents("tr").find('input[name="arrondi_devis_ht"]').val(new_prix_ht);
$(this).parents("tr").find('input[name="arrondi_devis_ttc"]').val(new_prix_ttc);
$(this).parents("tr").find('input[name="marge_pourcent"]').val(new_marge);
```

Since they are all in the same row, you may want to reuse the initial selector like so:

```
var $row = $(this).parents("tr");

$row.find('input[name="arrondi_devis_ht"]').val(new_prix_ht);
$row.find('input[name="arrondi_devis_ttc"]').val(new_prix_ttc);
$row.find('input[name="marge_pourcent"]').val(new_marge);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).parents("tr").find('input[name="arrondi_devis_ht"]').val(new_prix_ht);
$(this).parents("tr").find('input[name="arrondi_devis_ttc"]').val(new_prix_ttc);
$(this).parents("tr").find('input[name="marge_pourcent"]').val(new_marge);
```

You need to use **[.val()](http://api.jquery/com/val)** to set value to a input field.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).closest("tr").find('input[name="arrondi_devis_ht"]').val(new_prix_ht);
$(this).closest("tr").find('input[name="arrondi_devis_ttc"]').val(new_prix_ttc);
$(this).closest("tr").find('input[name="marge_pourcent"]').val(new_marge);
```

You can cache the `<tr>` than, you can simplify your code to:

```
var row = $(this).closest('tr');
row.find('input[name="arrondi_devis_ht"]').val(new_prix_ht);
row.find('input[name="arrondi_devis_ttc"]').val(new_prix_ttc);
row.find('input[name="marge_pourcent"]').val(new_marge);
```

Comment: It's déjà vu all over again... (OK, this is _slightly_ different...)

Comment: @nnnnnn. What do you mean? is traversing up until document vs just until the `<tr>` is only _"slightly different"_?

Comment: At first glance there were three near-identical answers. (But then I noticed you'd used `.closest()`, which is definitely better though it kind of spoils the Déjà vu joke.)

Comment: @nnnnnn. I'm sorry I didn't mean to spoil your joke... `:)`. Actually I could write a better answer if I knew what is `this`  and why he needs to go up the `<tr>`

Comment: $(this) is one of the text inputs. Basically, each one of their individual values depend on the values of the other two, so every time i change a value of one of the text inputs (the event triggering this is key up), the other two have to be changed. Since they're on the same line, i go up to the tr and then come down to find the other two inputs and change their values. I'm still a beginner, so i'm all ears if you have a more optimum solution :) Thanks already for your contribution.